# Return table of started and resolved cases sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table - Cases

```
ID  Date Created    Date Resolved
1   1/1/2015    
2   1/1/2015        1/1/2015
3   2/1/2015
4   1/1/2015        2/1/2015
5   4/1/2015
```

I must write an SQL query that returns the # of cases created vs. # of cases resolved per day
Expected result:

```
Day Created Resolved
1/1/2015    3   1
2/1/2015    1   1
3/1/2015    0   0
4/1/2015    1   0
```

I am trying something like:

```
SELECT 
  DateCreated as Day, 
  COUNT(DateCreated) as Created, 
  DateResolved as Resolved 
FROM cases 
GROUP BY Day;
```

But someting is wrong, someone can help me understand the logic i must implement?

Comment: Step 1. Store dates using a proper date data type. Then get back to us.

Answer (score 2):

You should use separate queries for each result and then combine them together using UNION.

Try this:

```sql
    SELECT day, SUM(created) as created, SUM(solved) as solved FROM
    (

    SELECT c1.date_created as day, COUNT(c1.id) as created, 0 as solved FROM cases c1 GROUP BY c1.date_created

    UNION 

    SELECT c2.date_solved as day, 0 as created, COUNT(c2.id) as solved FROM cases c2 WHERE c2.date_solved IS NOT NULL GROUP BY c2.date_solved
    ) as unionTable

    GROUP BY day;
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve most of your problem with `union all` and `group by`:

```
select dte, sum(created), sum(resolved)
from ((select date_created as dte, 1 as created, 0 as resolved
       from t
      ) union all
      (select date_resolved as dte, 0 as created, 1 as resolved
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by dte;
```

This does not produce the row:

```
3/1/2015    0   0
```

because the date is not in the original data.  There are various ways to generate it, depending on the database.  Or, you might have a calendar table lying around, filled with all the dates you could possibly need.

EDIT:

In MySQL, I would recommend:

```
select d.dte,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where t.date_created = d.dte
       ) as created,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where t.date_resolved = d.dte
       ) as resolved
from (select date('2015-01-01') as dte union all
      select date('2015-02-01') as dte union all
      select date('2015-03-01') as dte union all
      select date('2015-04-01') as dte 
     ) d;
```

Note:  With indexes on `t(date_created)` and `t(date_resolved)`, this is probably the fastest query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what database you are using so I'll give you a generic answer. You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to join both sides of the equation. For example:

```
select
  coalesce(c.d, r.d) as date,
  c.cnt as created,
  r.cnt as resolved
from (
  select date(date_created) as d, count(*) as cnt 
  from my_table group by date(date_created)
) c
full outer join ( 
  select date(date_resolved) as d, count(*) as cnt
  from my_table group by date(date_resolved)
) r on c.d = r.d
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, here is an option.

```
SELECT A.[DateCreated] [Day]
    , COUNT(id) [Created]
    , (SELECT COUNT( [B].[ID] ) FROM cases B WHERE B.[DateResolved] = A.[DateCreated] ) [Resolved]
FROM cases A
GROUP BY [A].[DateCreated]
```

This doesn't create the 03/01/2015 data row as it is not in the initial data set.